# JDK 17 package com.sun.javadoc does not exist

Tags: javadoc, java-17

While upgrading to jdk17 we can get error as package doesn't exist

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project test: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

[ERROR] C:\Users\test\git\java\com\util\test.java:[31,22] error: package com.sun.javadoc does not exist

Answer (score 4):

The `com.sun.javadoc` package was deprecated in Java 11, and has been removed for Java 17. Your code must be updated. Please refer to the [migration guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.javadoc/jdk/javadoc/doclet/package-summary.html#migration) for package `jdk.javadoc.doclet` for replacement APIs.

Comment: Don't see straight forward approach looks like it need to be modify completely(cannot just replace). eg: import com.sun.javadoc.RootDoc;
import jdk.javadoc.doclet.DocletEnvironment;